# Node.js / Expess.js. Static router not recognized if used with wildcard router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I use only this route with my all other routes, that static files served well:

```
var public_dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
app.use('/public', express.static(public_dir));
```

But when I add below these lines - all requests are catch with this router (not the previous one):

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/#!' + req.path);
});
```

It's strange to me, because `/public` definition comes first. But all request goes to last defined `/*` request handler.

Now, if I try to open page `http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/website/application.js` I become redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/#!/public/website/application.js`. Why it happens, and how to solve this situation in the best manner?

Thank you a lot!

---

Solution is simple. I have not working statement in list of middlewares.

```
app.use(app.router);
```

This is creates a problem of url routing. But it's strange that `node.js` did not tell me about "incorrect setup" of middleware.

Comment: you are using app.use with the first and app.get with the second..?

Comment: As @DrCord mentioned, app.[get|post|put|etc] methods are added to the router. Therefore, if you mount your router first, it will be used first.

Comment: Like Nick mentioned positions of router and static decide precedence. Please show how you use router and static (relative positions).

Comment: @NickMitchinson and @DrCord. I used `app.use('/public', ...)` before `qpp.get('/*', ...)` statement. If I delete `app.get()` statement that I see my static file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code but keep in mind that any request on something that doesn't exist will be catch by your get('/*', ...).

This said, you load `public_dir` on `/public` that's mean if `public_dir` is defined as `public/website/` you have to do `http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/application.js` in order to access a file locate at `/public/website/application.js`

Comment: yeah, you shouldn't have to include public into your path for files in the public folder...

Comment: I updated my code below. I used `/public` to navigate to `public directory` where I have some subdirectories (including `website`). I see my static file in browser when I have deleted `app.get('/*', ...)` definition only.

Comment: That's strange, something else must be interacting. I've recreated here https://github.com/BaNzounet/so-express what you've described, and it works.

Comment: @BaNz Yahooo! It's working!!! The problem was in `broken` definition of middleware `app.use(app.router);`